# SQL Server - Trigger handling multiple rows in INSERT pseudo table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using a trigger in SQL Server to capture changes into an audit table. Everything is working fine, except I noticed an instance when the audit table has some wrong data in it (eg. One row containing data from another row). I would guess this occurs <1%. Here is my current code.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Trigger] ON  [dbo].[Table]
FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    -- Detect inserts ------------------------------------------------------
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO AuditTable (Column1, Column2, etc.)
            SELECT 'I', Column1, Column2, etc.
            FROM inserted
        RETURN;
    END

    -- Detect deletes ------------------------------------------------------
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO AuditTable (Column1, Column2, etc.)
            SELECT 'D', Column1, Column2, etc.
            FROM deleted
        RETURN;
    END

    -- Detect updates ------------------------------------------------------
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted) AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO AuditTable (Column1, Column2, etc.)
            SELECT 'U', Column1, Column2, etc.
            FROM inserted
        RETURN;
    END
END;
```

After doing some research I am thinking this issue occurs because my code was written assuming that the pseudo INSERT table only kept 1 row at a time. This is the new trigger, which works, but I don't know if it will fix my problem. Any thoughts?

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Trigger] ON  [dbo].[Table]
FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    -- Detect inserts ------------------------------------------------------
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO AuditTable (Column1, Column2, etc.)
            SELECT 'I', Column1, Column2, etc.
            FROM inserted
        RETURN;
    END

    -- Detect deletes ------------------------------------------------------
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO AuditTable (Column1, Column2, etc.)
            SELECT 'D', Column1, Column2, etc.
            FROM deleted
        RETURN;
    END

    -- Detect updates ------------------------------------------------------
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted) AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO AuditTable (Column1, Column2, etc.)
            SELECT 'U', Column1, Column2, etc.

        -- new code --    
            FROM Table T
            INNER JOIN inserted i ON i.[Column1] = T.[Column1]

        RETURN;
    END
END;
```

---

UPDATE: I started this thread because I have triggers capturing changes to my tables in their own audit tables, but about 1% of the time, the trigger fails to capture a change. I had thought it was because of there being multiple rows in the pseudo tables, but I now think there's another reason. For whatever reason, my triggers fail to update the audit table or mess up the data somehow.

Should I implement TRY/CATCH?

Comment: If an update/insert/delete statement covers more than one record the trigger will only fire once. Your code seems correct at first glance

Comment: I dont understand the return statements. Why do you need them ? What's the point ?

Comment: Your first code should handle multi-row operations so there isn't a need to add the join. How are you determining you are getting data from another row?